# How to create a link from the welcome page to another ruby page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, blogs, contacts, railsapps

at the moment, my nav-bar content looks like this:

```
<li><%= link_to "Portfolio", projects_path, :class => "header" %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Articles", posts_path, :class => "header" %></li>
<li><%= link_to 'Contact',  contact_path, :class => "header" %></li>
```

The first two links work fine, but the last one doesn't. 
How do I refer correcty? The contact page is just a simple, static page (no projects, or blogs that get pushed).

This my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :contact
  get 'contact/index'
  resources :posts
  resources :projects
  get 'welcome/index'
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

And this is the controller

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end
end
```

If I take a look at the rake routes, I am get this:

```
contact_index GET    /contact(.:format)           contact#index
              POST   /contact(.:format)           contact#create
  new_contact GET    /contact/new(.:format)       contact#new
 edit_contact GET    /contact/:id/edit(.:format)  contact#edit
      contact GET    /contact/:id(.:format)       contact#show
              PATCH  /contact/:id(.:format)       contact#update
              PUT    /contact/:id(.:format)       contact#update
              DELETE /contact/:id(.:format)       contact#destroy
              GET    /contact/index(.:format)     contact#index
```

I am new at ruby and I am looking forward to help. Thanks already in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your third line with following line:

```
<li><%= link_to 'Contact', contact_index_path, class: "header" %></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `get 'contact/index'` from your routes file and try.

You already have a path for index of `contact`, when you added `resources :contact`

Comment: Dear Kumar, unfortunately that was not enough. When I go to my localhost I get the following error: 
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"contact"} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Is your controller name `ContactController` or `ContactsController`? If its plural, you should be doing `resources :contacts` instead.

Comment: It is contact_controller.rb

Comment: Do you have only one method in your contact controller? `index`?